# Altering twitter4j to search

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am currently creating code that should search through tweets based on keywords.  i originally created a streamer using the twitter4j API, only to find out that you cant filter multiple filters.  my code for this is listed below.

```
public class TweetStreamer {
public static void stream(String[] apiKeys, String[] stopwords, long[] users, double[][] coordinates, BiConsumer<Status, String> fn) throws InterruptedException {
    // Save the arguments
    String consumerKey = apiKeys[0];
    String consumerSecret = apiKeys[1];
    String token = apiKeys[2];
    String secret = apiKeys[3];

    // Store the configuration
    ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    config.setDebugEnabled(true);
    config.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    config.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    config.setOAuthAccessToken(token);
    config.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(secret);

    config.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

    // Create a status listener. When a new tweet arives, the function object will accept it.
    StatusListener listener = new TwitterStatusListener(fn);

    // Create the filter. Can filter:
    //  * by Users (follow[])
    //  * by Stopword (track[])
    //  * by Location (locations[][])
    //  * by Language (language[])
    FilterQuery filter = new FilterQuery();
    filter.track(stopwords);
    filter.follow(users);
    filter.locations(coordinates);

    // Create the stream-object
    // Documentation: http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html
    TwitterStream stream = new TwitterStreamFactory(config.build()).getInstance();

    stream.addListener(listener);
    stream.filter(filter);
}
}
```

I have wrote some code that will work as a search using Query instead of FilterQuery. however im struggling to replace one with the other.

my search code is as follows:

```
public class TweetGetter {

/**
 * @param response
 */
public void searchTwitter(String searchString) {

    /*
     * The TwitterFactory is what interacts directly with Twitter
     */
    ConfigUtil twitterConfig = new ConfigUtil();
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(twitterConfig.configureTwitter().build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
    try {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.setLang("en");
        // query.setCount(10);
        query.setQuery(searchString);

        double lat = 28.6538100;
        System.out.println();


        double lon =77.2289700;
        System.out.println();

        //GeoLocation gl = new GeoLocation(28.6538100, 77.2289700);
        GeoLocation gl = new GeoLocation(lat, lon);


        double rad = 1000;
        System.out.println();

        //query.setGeoCode(gl, 1500, Query.KILOMETERS);
        query.setGeoCode(gl, rad, Query.KILOMETERS);
        query.setLang("en");
        query.setCount(500);

        // The object the will contain the results of the query
        QueryResult result;

        do {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

            SaveUtil saver = new SaveUtil();
            saver.saveTweets(tweets);

        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);

    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        // System.exit(-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    scan.close();

}

}
```

where saveUtil simply saves data in a text file.

is there anyway i could modify the search code to replace the TweetStreamer?

Comment: just to clarify, tweetStreamer automatically inserts into an SQL database